# AES encryption and decryption does not match

Tags: c, encryption, aes

Hi I am trying to test the code in the book named *"Implementing SSL/TLS Using Cryptography and PKI"*. I try to encrypt a simple array and decrypt it again. But, I always find the first 16 bytes are not decrypted correclty. Here is one example,

Plain Text:

> b0000000000000000000000000000000f0000000000000000000000000000000e0000000000000000000000000000000f0000000000000000000000000000000

Encrypted Text:

> 68a6e7307be65351838d9157e35be74f3faa11761ef6a4794e36c970ffc724ef8070519d3cac6c5e396c5466034b2e0c32cd0203599dd63716f3318f7852f577

Decrypted Text:

> 82cd0203599dd63716f3318f7852f576f0000000000000000000000000000000e0000000000000000000000000000000f0000000000000000000000000000000

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/** 
 * Check to see if the input starts with "0x"; if it does, return the decoded
 * bytes of the following data (presumed to be hex coded). If not, just return
 * the contents. This routine allocates memory, so has to be free'd.
 */
int hex_decode( const unsigned char *input, unsigned char **decoded )
{  
  int i;
  int len;

  if ( strncmp( "0x", input, 2 ) )
  {
    len = strlen( input ) + 1;
    *decoded = malloc( len );
    strcpy( *decoded, input );
    len--;
  }
  else
  {
    len = ( strlen( input ) >> 1 ) - 1;
    *decoded = malloc( len );
    for ( i = 2; i < strlen( input ); i += 2 )
    {
      (*decoded)[ ( ( i / 2 ) - 1 ) ] =
        ( ( ( input[ i ] <= '9' ) ? input[ i ] - '0' : 
        ( ( tolower( input[ i ] ) ) - 'a' + 10 ) ) << 4 ) |
        ( ( input[ i + 1 ] <= '9' ) ? input[ i + 1 ] - '0' : 
        ( ( tolower( input[ i + 1 ] ) ) - 'a' + 10 ) );
    }
  } 

  return len;
}

void show_hex( const unsigned char *array, int length )
{
  while ( length-- )
  {
    printf( "%.02x", *array++ );
  }
  printf( "\n" );
}

static void xor( unsigned char *target, const unsigned char *src, int len )
{
  while ( len-- )
  {
    *target++ ^= *src++;
  }
}

static void rot_word( unsigned char *w )
{
  unsigned char tmp;

  tmp = w[ 0 ];
  w[ 0 ] = w[ 1 ];
  w[ 1 ] = w[ 2 ];
  w[ 2 ] = w[ 3 ];
  w[ 3 ] = tmp;
}

static unsigned char sbox[ 16 ][ 16 ] = {
{ 0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 
  0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76 },
{ 0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 
  0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0 },
{ 0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 
  0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15 },
{ 0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 
  0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75 },
{ 0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 
  0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84 },
{ 0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 
  0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf },
{ 0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 
  0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8 },
{ 0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 
  0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2 },
{ 0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 
  0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73 },
{ 0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 
  0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb },
{ 0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 
  0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79 },
{ 0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 
  0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08 },
{ 0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 
  0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a },
{ 0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 
  0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e },
{ 0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 
  0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf },
{ 0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 
  0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16 },
};

static void sub_word( unsigned char *w )
{
  int i = 0;

  for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
  {
    w[ i ] = sbox[ ( w[ i ] & 0xF0 ) >> 4 ][ w[ i ] & 0x0F ];
  } 
} 

static void compute_key_schedule( const unsigned char *key,
                 int key_length,
                 unsigned char w[ ][ 4 ] )
{
  int i;
  int key_words = key_length >> 2;
  unsigned char rcon = 0x01;

  // First, copy the key directly into the key schedule
  memcpy( w, key, key_length );
  for ( i = key_words; i < 4 * ( key_words + 7 ); i++ )
  {
    memcpy( w[ i ], w[ i - 1 ], 4 );
    if ( !( i % key_words ) )
    {
      rot_word( w[ i ] );
      sub_word( w[ i ] );
      if ( !( i % 36 ) )
      {
        rcon = 0x1b;
      }
      w[ i ][ 0 ] ^= rcon;
      rcon <<= 1;
    }
    else if ( ( key_words > 6 ) && ( ( i % key_words ) == 4 ) )
    {
     sub_word( w[ i ] );  
    }
    w[ i ][ 0 ] ^= w[ i - key_words ][ 0 ];
    w[ i ][ 1 ] ^= w[ i - key_words ][ 1 ];
    w[ i ][ 2 ] ^= w[ i - key_words ][ 2 ];
    w[ i ][ 3 ] ^= w[ i - key_words ][ 3 ];
  }
}

static void add_round_key( unsigned char state[ ][ 4 ], 
                           unsigned char w[ ][ 4 ] )
{
  int c, r;

  for ( c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
  {
    for ( r = 0; r < 4; r++ )
    {
      state[ r ][ c ] = state[ r ][ c ] ^ w[ c ][ r ];
    }
  }
}

static void sub_bytes( unsigned char state[ ][ 4 ] )
{
  int r, c;

  for ( r = 0; r < 4; r++ )
  {
    for ( c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
    {
      state[ r ][ c ] = sbox[ ( state[ r ][ c ] & 0xF0 ) >> 4 ]
                            [ state[ r ][ c ] & 0x0F ];
    }
   }
}

static void shift_rows( unsigned char state[ ][ 4 ] )
{
  int tmp;

  tmp = state[ 1 ][ 0 ];
  state[ 1 ][ 0 ] = state[ 1 ][ 1 ];
  state[ 1 ][ 1 ] = state[ 1 ][ 2 ];
  state[ 1 ][ 2 ] = state[ 1 ][ 3 ];
  state[ 1 ][ 3 ] = tmp;

  tmp = state[ 2 ][ 0 ];
  state[ 2 ][ 0 ] = state[ 2 ][ 2 ];
  state[ 2 ][ 2 ] = tmp;
  tmp = state[ 2 ][ 1 ];
  state[ 2 ][ 1 ] = state[ 2 ][ 3 ];
  state[ 2 ][ 3 ] = tmp;

  tmp = state[ 3 ][ 3 ];
  state[ 3 ][ 3 ] = state[ 3 ][ 2 ];
  state[ 3 ][ 2 ] = state[ 3 ][ 1 ];
  state[ 3 ][ 1 ] = state[ 3 ][ 0 ];
  state[ 3 ][ 0 ] = tmp;
}

unsigned char xtime( unsigned char x )
{
  return ( x << 1 ) ^ ( ( x & 0x80 ) ? 0x1b : 0x00 );
}

unsigned char dot( unsigned char x, unsigned char y )
{ 
  unsigned char mask; 
  unsigned char product = 0; 

  for ( mask = 0x01; mask; mask <<= 1 )
  {
    if ( y & mask ) 
    {
      product ^= x; 
    }
    x = xtime( x );
   }

 return product;
}

static void mix_columns( unsigned char s[ ][ 4 ] )
{
  int c;
  unsigned char t[ 4 ];

  for ( c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
  {
    t[ 0 ] = dot( 2, s[ 0 ][ c ] ) ^ dot( 3, s[ 1 ][ c ] ) ^ 
             s[ 2 ][ c ] ^ s[ 3 ][ c ];
    t[ 1 ] = s[ 0 ][ c ] ^ dot( 2, s[ 1 ][ c ] ) ^ 
             dot( 3, s[ 2 ][ c ] ) ^ s[ 3 ][ c ];
    t[ 2 ] = s[ 0 ][ c ] ^ s[ 1 ][ c ] ^ dot( 2, s[ 2 ][ c ] ) ^ 
             dot( 3, s[ 3 ] [ c ] );
    t[ 3 ] = dot( 3, s[ 0 ][ c ] ) ^ s[ 1 ][ c ] ^ s[ 2 ][ c ] ^ 
             dot( 2, s[ 3 ][ c ] );
    s[ 0 ][ c ] = t[ 0 ];
    s[ 1 ][ c ] = t[ 1 ];
    s[ 2 ][ c ] = t[ 2 ];
    s[ 3 ][ c ] = t[ 3 ];
  }
}

static void aes_block_encrypt( const unsigned char *input_block,
                unsigned char *output_block,
                const unsigned char *key,
                int key_size )
{
  int r, c;
  int round;
  int nr;
  unsigned char state[ 4 ][ 4 ];
  unsigned char w[ 60 ][ 4 ];

  for ( r = 0; r < 4; r++ )
  {
    for ( c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
    {
      state[ r ][ c ] = input_block[ r + ( 4 * c ) ];
    }
  }
  // rounds = key size in 4-byte words + 6
  nr = ( key_size >> 2 ) + 6;

  compute_key_schedule( key, key_size, w );

  add_round_key( state, &w[ 0 ] );

  for ( round = 0; round < nr; round++ )
  {
    sub_bytes( state );
    shift_rows( state );
    if ( round < ( nr - 1 ) )
    {
      mix_columns( state );
    }
    add_round_key( state, &w[ ( round + 1 ) * 4 ] );
  }

  for ( r = 0; r < 4; r++ )
  { 
    for ( c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
    {
      output_block[ r + ( 4 * c ) ] = state[ r ][ c ];
    }
  }
}

static void inv_shift_rows( unsigned char state[ ][ 4 ] )
{ 
  int tmp;

  tmp = state[ 1 ][ 2 ];
  state[ 1 ][ 2 ] = state[ 1 ][ 1 ];
  state[ 1 ][ 1 ] = state[ 1 ][ 0 ];
  state[ 1 ][ 0 ] = state[ 1 ][ 3 ];
  state[ 1 ][ 3 ] = tmp;

  tmp = state[ 2 ][ 0 ];
  state[ 2 ][ 0 ] = state[ 2 ][ 2 ];
  state[ 2 ][ 2 ] = tmp;
  tmp = state[ 2 ][ 1 ];
  state[ 2 ][ 1 ] = state[ 2 ][ 3 ];
  state[ 2 ][ 3 ] = tmp;

  tmp = state[ 3 ][ 0 ];
  state[ 3 ][ 0 ] = state[ 3 ][ 1 ];
  state[ 3 ][ 1 ] = state[ 3 ][ 2 ];
  state[ 3 ][ 2 ] = state[ 3 ][ 3 ];
  state[ 3 ][ 3 ] = tmp;
}

static unsigned char inv_sbox[ 16 ][ 16 ] = {
{ 0x52, 0x09, 0x6a, 0xd5, 0x30, 0x36, 0xa5, 0x38, 
  0xbf, 0x40, 0xa3, 0x9e, 0x81, 0xf3, 0xd7, 0xfb },
{ 0x7c, 0xe3, 0x39, 0x82, 0x9b, 0x2f, 0xff, 0x87, 
  0x34, 0x8e, 0x43, 0x44, 0xc4, 0xde, 0xe9, 0xcb },
{ 0x54, 0x7b, 0x94, 0x32, 0xa6, 0xc2, 0x23, 0x3d, 
  0xee, 0x4c, 0x95, 0x0b, 0x42, 0xfa, 0xc3, 0x4e },
{ 0x08, 0x2e, 0xa1, 0x66, 0x28, 0xd9, 0x24, 0xb2, 
  0x76, 0x5b, 0xa2, 0x49, 0x6d, 0x8b, 0xd1, 0x25 },
{ 0x72, 0xf8, 0xf6, 0x64, 0x86, 0x68, 0x98, 0x16, 
  0xd4, 0xa4, 0x5c, 0xcc, 0x5d, 0x65, 0xb6, 0x92 },
{ 0x6c, 0x70, 0x48, 0x50, 0xfd, 0xed, 0xb9, 0xda, 
  0x5e, 0x15, 0x46, 0x57, 0xa7, 0x8d, 0x9d, 0x84 },
{ 0x90, 0xd8, 0xab, 0x00, 0x8c, 0xbc, 0xd3, 0x0a, 
  0xf7, 0xe4, 0x58, 0x05, 0xb8, 0xb3, 0x45, 0x06 },
{ 0xd0, 0x2c, 0x1e, 0x8f, 0xca, 0x3f, 0x0f, 0x02, 
  0xc1, 0xaf, 0xbd, 0x03, 0x01, 0x13, 0x8a, 0x6b },
{ 0x3a, 0x91, 0x11, 0x41, 0x4f, 0x67, 0xdc, 0xea, 
  0x97, 0xf2, 0xcf, 0xce, 0xf0, 0xb4, 0xe6, 0x73 },
{ 0x96, 0xac, 0x74, 0x22, 0xe7, 0xad, 0x35, 0x85, 
  0xe2, 0xf9, 0x37, 0xe8, 0x1c, 0x75, 0xdf, 0x6e },
{ 0x47, 0xf1, 0x1a, 0x71, 0x1d, 0x29, 0xc5, 0x89, 
  0x6f, 0xb7, 0x62, 0x0e, 0xaa, 0x18, 0xbe, 0x1b },
{ 0xfc, 0x56, 0x3e, 0x4b, 0xc6, 0xd2, 0x79, 0x20, 
  0x9a, 0xdb, 0xc0, 0xfe, 0x78, 0xcd, 0x5a, 0xf4 },
{ 0x1f, 0xdd, 0xa8, 0x33, 0x88, 0x07, 0xc7, 0x31, 
  0xb1, 0x12, 0x10, 0x59, 0x27, 0x80, 0xec, 0x5f },
{ 0x60, 0x51, 0x7f, 0xa9, 0x19, 0xb5, 0x4a, 0x0d, 
  0x2d, 0xe5, 0x7a, 0x9f, 0x93, 0xc9, 0x9c, 0xef },
{ 0xa0, 0xe0, 0x3b, 0x4d, 0xae, 0x2a, 0xf5, 0xb0, 
  0xc8, 0xeb, 0xbb, 0x3c, 0x83, 0x53, 0x99, 0x61 },
{ 0x17, 0x2b, 0x04, 0x7e, 0xba, 0x77, 0xd6, 0x26, 
  0xe1, 0x69, 0x14, 0x63, 0x55, 0x21, 0x0c, 0x7d },
};

static void inv_sub_bytes( unsigned char state[ ][ 4 ] )
{
  int r, c;

  for ( r = 0; r < 4; r++ )
  {
    for ( c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
    {
      state[ r ][ c ] = inv_sbox[ ( state[ r ][ c ] & 0xF0 ) >> 4 ]
                                [ state[ r ][ c ] & 0x0F ];
    }
  }
}

static void inv_mix_columns( unsigned char s[ ][ 4 ] )
{
  int c;
  unsigned char t[ 4 ];

  for ( c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
  {
    t[ 0 ] = dot( 0x0e, s[ 0 ][ c ] ) ^ dot( 0x0b, s[ 1 ][ c ] ) ^ 
             dot( 0x0d, s[ 2 ][ c ] ) ^ dot( 0x09, s[ 3 ][ c ] );
    t[ 1 ] = dot( 0x09, s[ 0 ][ c ] ) ^ dot( 0x0e, s[ 1 ][ c ] ) ^ 
             dot( 0x0b, s[ 2 ][ c ] ) ^ dot( 0x0d, s[ 3 ][ c ] );
    t[ 2 ] = dot( 0x0d, s[ 0 ][ c ] ) ^ dot( 0x09, s[ 1 ][ c ] ) ^ 
             dot( 0x0e, s[ 2 ][ c ] ) ^ dot( 0x0b, s[ 3 ][ c ] );
    t[ 3 ] = dot( 0x0b, s[ 0 ][ c ] ) ^ dot( 0x0d, s[ 1 ][ c ] ) ^ 
             dot( 0x09, s[ 2 ][ c ] ) ^ dot( 0x0e, s[ 3 ][ c ] );
    s[ 0 ][ c ] = t[ 0 ];
    s[ 1 ][ c ] = t[ 1 ];
    s[ 2 ][ c ] = t[ 2 ];
    s[ 3 ][ c ] = t[ 3 ];
  }
}

static void aes_block_decrypt( const unsigned char *input_block,
                unsigned char *output_block,
                const unsigned char *key,
                int key_size ) 
{
  int r, c;
  int round;
  int nr;
  unsigned char state[ 4 ][ 4 ];
  unsigned char w[ 60 ][ 4 ];

  for ( r = 0; r < 4; r++ )
  {
    for ( c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
    {
      state[ r ][ c ] = input_block[ r + ( 4 * c ) ];
    }
  }
  // rounds = key size in 4-byte words + 6
  nr = ( key_size >> 2 ) + 6;

  compute_key_schedule( key, key_size, w );

  add_round_key( state, &w[ nr * 4 ] );

  for ( round = nr; round > 0; round-- )
  {
    inv_shift_rows( state );
    inv_sub_bytes( state );
    add_round_key( state, &w[ ( round - 1 ) * 4 ] );
    if ( round > 1 )
    {
      inv_mix_columns( state );
    }
  }

  for ( r = 0; r < 4; r++ )
  { 
    for ( c = 0; c < 4; c++ )
    {
      output_block[ r + ( 4 * c ) ] = state[ r ][ c ];
    }
  }
}

#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE 16

static void aes_encrypt( const unsigned char *input,
             int input_len,
             unsigned char *output,
             const unsigned char *iv,
             const unsigned char *key,
             int key_length )
{
  unsigned char input_block[ AES_BLOCK_SIZE ];

  while ( input_len >= AES_BLOCK_SIZE )
  { 
    memcpy( input_block, input, AES_BLOCK_SIZE );
    xor( input_block, iv, AES_BLOCK_SIZE ); // implement CBC
    aes_block_encrypt( input_block, output, key, key_length );
    memcpy( ( void * ) iv, ( void * ) output, AES_BLOCK_SIZE ); // CBC
    input += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    output += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    input_len -= AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
  }
}

static void aes_decrypt( const unsigned char *input,
             int input_len,
             unsigned char *output,
             const unsigned char *iv,
             const unsigned char *key,
             int key_length )
{
  while ( input_len >= AES_BLOCK_SIZE )
  {
    aes_block_decrypt( input, output, key, key_length );
    xor( output, iv, AES_BLOCK_SIZE );
    memcpy( ( void * ) iv, ( void * ) input, AES_BLOCK_SIZE ); // CBC
    input += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    output += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    input_len -= AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
  }
}

void aes_128_encrypt( const unsigned char *plaintext,
           const int plaintext_len,
           unsigned char ciphertext[],
           void *iv,
           const unsigned char *key )
{
  aes_encrypt( plaintext, plaintext_len, ciphertext, 
    ( const unsigned char * ) iv, key, 16 );
}

void aes_128_decrypt( const unsigned char *ciphertext,
           const int ciphertext_len,
           unsigned char plaintext[],
           void *iv,
           const unsigned char *key )
{
  aes_decrypt( ciphertext, ciphertext_len, plaintext, 
    ( const unsigned char * ) iv, key, 16 );
}

void aes_256_encrypt( const unsigned char *plaintext,
           const int plaintext_len,
           unsigned char ciphertext[],
           void *iv,
           const unsigned char *key )
{
  aes_encrypt( plaintext, plaintext_len, ciphertext, 
    ( const unsigned char * ) iv, key, 32 );
}

void aes_256_decrypt( const unsigned char *ciphertext,
           const int ciphertext_len,
           unsigned char plaintext[],
           void *iv,
           const unsigned char *key )
{
  aes_decrypt( ciphertext, ciphertext_len, plaintext, 
    ( const unsigned char *) iv, key, 32 );
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] )
{
  unsigned char key[] = 
  {
    0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  } ;

  unsigned char input[] =
  {
    // 0xf3, 0x44, 0x81, 0xec, 0x3c, 0xc6, 0x27, 0xba, 0xcd, 0x5d, 0xc3, 0xfb, 0x08, 0xf2, 0x73, 0xe6
    0xB0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xF0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xE0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0xF0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  } ;

  unsigned char iv[] = 
  {
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01,
  } ;

  int key_len = sizeof(key);
  int input_len = sizeof(input);
  int iv_len = sizeof(iv);
  unsigned char *ciphertext = ( unsigned char * ) malloc( input_len );
  aes_256_encrypt( input, input_len, ciphertext, iv, key );
  show_hex( ciphertext, input_len );  
  unsigned char *plaintext = ( unsigned char * ) malloc( input_len );
  aes_256_decrypt( ciphertext, input_len, plaintext, iv, key );
  show_hex( plaintext, input_len );
  free( ciphertext );
  free( plaintext );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you expect someone to study 500+ lines of code to find you error I doubt that will happen especially with the limited descriptive text. The title mentions AES and the question mentions SSL, PKI and TLS. You really need to narrow down the question and code. Also missing are the inputs.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a wrong **IV**. Make sure the IV is the same at the start of decrypt as it was at the start of encrypt.

In CBC mode the input data to a block is xor'ed with the output of the previous  block and the **IV** is used to start this process. In the code above, the IV is used as the buffer for this, and thus the IV ends up being overwritten during encryption.

If you reset the **IV** before decryption, your code works as expected.

Edit:

The line in question is in the methode `aes_encrypt`:

```
memcpy( ( void * ) iv, ( void * ) output, AES_BLOCK_SIZE ); // CBC
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My problem is solved.